# mo.js - Apply the same effect on all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I apply the same effect on each button on the page?

The following variable working with the first button only

```
el1 = document.querySelector("button.icobutton")
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KyMVeL

Comment: Use `querySelectorAll()`

Comment: @JosanIracheta Unfortunately, not working, could you please update the pin?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a collection of the HTML elements. You have to loop through each one.